# Powershell JSON: Extracting Values from Array nested in a object

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to extract values from JSON Array that is wrapped in a JSON object:

I cannot use | formatFrom-JSON as it returns just the first line.

I wonder how do I bypass this and get just the array with those details from response.

I am interested in those keys and values from Apple Stock.

I have searched quite a lot but no uck so far...

```
Code:

{
   "quoteResponse":{
      "result":[
         {
            "language":"en-US",
            "region":"US",
            "quoteType":"EQUITY",
            "quoteSourceName":"Delayed Quote",
            "triggerable":true,
            "currency":"USD",
            "marketState":"CLOSED",
            "exchange":"NMS",
            "shortName":"Apple Inc.",
            "longName":"Apple Inc.",
            "messageBoardId":"finmb_24937",
            "exchangeTimezoneName":"America/New_York",
            "exchangeTimezoneShortName":"EDT",
            "gmtOffSetMilliseconds":-14400000,
            "market":"us_market",
            "esgPopulated":false,
            "regularMarketDayHigh":123.7,
            "regularMarketDayRange":"110.89 - 123.7",
            "regularMarketDayLow":110.89,
            "regularMarketVolume":332607163,
            "regularMarketPreviousClose":120.88,
            "bid":120.01,
            "ask":120.1,
            "bidSize":12,
            "askSize":9,
            "fullExchangeName":"NasdaqGS",
            "financialCurrency":"USD",
            "regularMarketOpen":120.07,
            "averageDailyVolume3Month":165333146,
            "averageDailyVolume10Day":191317114,
            "fiftyTwoWeekLowChange":68.1925,
            "fiftyTwoWeekLowChangePercent":1.29232,
            "epsCurrentYear":3.24,
            "priceEpsCurrentYear":37.333332,
            "sharesOutstanding":17102499840,
            "bookValue":4.218,
            "fiftyDayAverage":111.70643,
            "fiftyDayAverageChange":9.253571,
            "fiftyDayAverageChangePercent":0.0828383,
            "twoHundredDayAverage":85.37846,
            "twoHundredDayAverageChange":35.581535,
            "twoHundredDayAverageChangePercent":0.4167507,
            "marketCap":2068718419968,
            "forwardPE":31.255816,
            "priceToBook":28.6771,
            "sourceInterval":15,
            "exchangeDataDelayedBy":0,
            "tradeable":false,
            "fiftyTwoWeekRange":"52.7675 - 137.98",
            "fiftyTwoWeekHighChange":-17.019997,
            "fiftyTwoWeekHighChangePercent":-0.12335119,
            "fiftyTwoWeekLow":52.7675,
            "fiftyTwoWeekHigh":137.98,
            "dividendDate":1597276800,
            "earningsTimestamp":1596126600,
            "earningsTimestampStart":1603882740,
            "earningsTimestampEnd":1604318400,
            "trailingAnnualDividendRate":0.782,
            "trailingPE":36.699028,
            "trailingAnnualDividendYield":0.006469226,
            "epsTrailingTwelveMonths":3.296,
            "epsForward":3.87,
            "firstTradeDateMilliseconds":345479400000,
            "priceHint":2,
            "postMarketChangePercent":-0.79365003,
            "postMarketTime":1599263998,
            "postMarketPrice":120.0,
            "postMarketChange":-0.9599991,
            "regularMarketChange":0.08000183,
            "regularMarketChangePercent":0.06618285,
            "regularMarketTime":1599249602,
            "regularMarketPrice":120.96,
            "displayName":"Apple",
            "symbol":"AAPL"
         }
      ],
      "error":null
   }
}
```

Comment: if you use `ConvertFrom-Json` on that, and save the result to `$Test`, you can address things via `$Test.quoteResponse.result`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.

- those properties are:

Write-Host($results.quoteResponse.result.symbol)
Write-Host($results.quoteResponse.result.fiftyDayAverageChange)

perfect thank you!